# Incomplete background-image while keyboard pops up in mobile devices

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have body and HTML with `height: 100%` because of `vertical-align` stuff for container (center container). my problem I have form here and when I **focus textbox** in form normally browser force page to top and I'm ok with this. the point is why my background become incomplete and **defective** when the keyboard pops up in mobile??

```
<div class="container d-flex h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="row justify-content-center" id="Level-1">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <p>sadddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
                    <p>sadddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
                    <p>sadddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
                    <p>sadddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
                    <p>sadddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
                    <p>sadddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
                    <p>sadddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
                    <p>sadddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
                </div>
                <div class="w-100"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control rounded stroke text-center" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="phone number">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <button onclick="" type="submit" class="btn btn-block rounded buttonStyle " id="SendPhone">SEND</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my style:

```
html{
  height: 100%;
  background: #1c7430;
}

body{
  height: 100%;
  background: url("../images/BG-web.jpg") center/cover no-repeat;
}
.rounded{
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}
.stroke{
  border: 2px solid #1c7430;
}
.buttonStyle{
  background-color: $orange_color;
}
.buttonStyle:disabled{
  background-color: $disabled_color;
}
.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100vh; /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: @AkberIqbal please pay attention when creating a snippet. The code contain SASS variable, is missing an image path and there is no include of bootstrap CSS. Make sure you have these elements to be able to have a *runnable* code.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, acknowledged - will try to be careful going forward, Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

The reason is when the keyboard pops up the viewport of the device shrinks and the image gets adjusted to the reduced height. The solution is to make sure your div items always ensures a 100% of height.

Consider making

```
html,body{
   height:100%;
}
.container{
   min-height:100%;
}
```

Instead of setting your background inside the body consider making an extra div with class .background, set it's position to relative and height 100%

```
.background{
    position:relative;
    background:url("yourimage") cover no-repeat;
    height:100%;

}
```

set the form contents inside a div with class .form-contents and set position absolute

```
.form-contents{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: sorry would you show me the final code . because with your code my form will come to center of the page

Comment: still same problem